# Why after that I lost SSH connection during an installation I obtain this "Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open" error message?

Tags: bash, software-installation, ssh, dpkg, lock

I am not so into Linux and I have the following problem.

I was installing RedMine on a remote Ubuntu Server via SSH, following the official tutorial: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Ubuntu_step_by_step

The installation process is pretty simple but when I was performing this statment:

```
sudo apt-get install redmine redmine-mysql
```

I lost connection...so I come back into my server reconnecting to it...so I perform again this command but now I am obtaining this error message:

```
*** System restart required ***
Last login: Fri Nov 11 11:57:11 2016 from 91.253.121.46
root@Betrivius-VPS:~# apt-get install redmine redmine-mysql
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
root@Betrivius-VPS:~#
```

Reading online it seems that it means that the prvious installation process is not ended.

So I don't know if I can retrieve it in some way or abort it. When I log into my remote server appear the message **System restart required**. I don't know if this message is causated by this situation or not and I don't know if restart my server will solve this issue.

So what is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Is there any other process running that involves in software installation or updation? What does 'top' say? If yes, then 'pkill <PID>'